# I want to get an integer input from a user and then make the for loop iterate through that number, and then call a function that many times

Tags: python

so I've been struggling with this for a while now. I want my program to ask a user "How many times to print Hello world?" and then get the number from that and use it in a for loop to call a function. Here is my Python code:

```
timestoprint = input("How many times to print hello?")

for i in timestoprint:
    printHello()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the number has to be an integer, not a string as the string just does length.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to convert the input to integer:

```py
timestoprint = int(input("How many times to print hello?"))
```

Then you have to use `range` builting generator and use it

```py
for x in range(timestoprint):
    printHello()
```

How does range work?

You have the option to provide arguments to range in any of the following configurations:

`range(number)`  which generates counting from 0 to number-1 at increment of 1

`range(start, stop)` which generates counting from start to stop-1 at increment of 1

`range(start, stop, step)` which generates counting from start to stop-1 at increment of step

You might also want to validate the user input which can be done by replacing the input statement with a forever while loop which breaks once the user provides valid input

```py
while True:
    timestoprint = input("How many times to print hello?")
    if timestoprint.isnumeric():  # Check if input is a number
        timestoprint = int(timestoprint)  # Convert it to number
        break  # Break the while loop
    else:  # if it is not a number
        print("The input is not a number.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
for i in timestoprint:
    printHello()
```

instead of

```
for i in range(timestoprint):
    printHello()
```

You also forgot to convert `timestopprint` to an `int`

This works for me:

```
timestoprint = int(input("How many times to print hello?"))

for i in range(timestoprint):
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `input` returns a string, whereas you want an `int`. You'll need to do a conversion. Second, for loops only take *iterables*, not integers, so you want to use `range` to get the values to iterate over.

```
timestoprint = int(input("How many times to print hello?"))

for i in range(timestoprint):
    printHello()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you must iterate over the integer part of `timestoprint` through `range` function in Python:

```
timestoprint = input("How many times to print hello?")

for i in range(int(timestoprint)):
    printHello()
```